# Make graphical item stay together with the mouse cursor

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a graphical item with x and y bound to the mouse position. When I move the mouse fast, the item goes after the cursor, smoothly animating towards the current position. I'd like it to keep the same position as the cursor all the time. Is it possible?

Current code:

```
Item{
    width: 800;   height: 600;

    Rectangle{
        width: 50;  height: 50;  color: "red";
        x: area.mouseX;  
        y: area.mouseY;
    }

    MouseArea{
        id: area
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnable: true
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess that's performance issue, actually the Rectangle keeps the same coords as the cursor.

Comment: @folibis Thanks for the observation. Yeah, printing the coords shows the same values for both. Maybe the QT engine draws the objects before updating the bindings, making the rectangle 1 frame late visually. Still couldn't find a solution...

Comment: How do you want to use that?

Comment: Actually I use a Text object instead of a rectangle. Effect of clicks on my interface depend more on app state than on the hovered area, so I label the cursor with the next action. Also, exact mouse coordinates sometimes matter for a click, so I show them just beside the cursor. The delay from QT does not break this, but it's a little annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial solution...

I included a cursor picture in the graphical item and made the real mouse cursor invisible (`cursorShape: Qt.BlankCursor`).

This fake cursor has the same latency to user input as I was already noticing in the bound item, but at least all parts stay together now.